# JFrog Artifactory installation from Docker gives the error: unauthorized: The client does not have permission for manifest

Tags: artifactory

Following the instructions [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#114759846aa77ee5734e34d7b8d6fba728e7f646f), I've tried to install Jfrog Artifactory (OSS version) via Docker, but I get an error:

```bash
$ docker run --name artifactory -v $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
Unable to find image 'releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: The client does not have permission for manifest.
See 'docker run --help'.
$
```

It seems that the Docker image repo isn't accepting anonymous downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with latest tag, and we fixed the tag.

Thanks for updating us.